# move from login page to main page in ionic using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

my code is working fine. but when i click on login button it changes the state as shown in the pic, it is changing its url but not opening that page.any help how can i redirect to next page?
[image: before click on login page]

[image: after click on login page]

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="login">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeLogin()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="doLogin()">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

   .state('app.menu', {
    url: '/home',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.search', {
     url: '/search',
     views: {
    '   menuContent': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
        }
     }
  })
});
```

**Controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $state) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    $state.go('app.search');

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})
```

Comment: where is the `'app.search'` state

Comment: its a new blank page till now

Comment: there is no state define for search in `$stateProvider` define a state

Comment: i did see 
 .state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
      }
    }
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the search state being a child state of the app state (which displays your login).

So it will first display the template with the login, and this template does not include anything to help the other state being shown.

I think you want your states to be :
login with url /login
app with url /app and abstract
And then app.search with url /search.

Then in your url bar you will see /app/search and it will be the right URL and right state you are looking for.

Comment: what i should do?

Comment: As I said you should replace the app state with login state and a /login url.
Then make your state called app.menu => menu and make its url /state.
Then I think you should see things working as you expect ;)

Comment: Basically this is because a . in the state means creating a child state of a state.
So state.childState.childStateOfChildState and so on ;)